# best method for jQuery to hide only the next element when associated element contains string

Tags: jquery

I have a case where I want to hide an element("target") based on the text value of another element("test").
I have code which hides ALL the cases of element("target") when I find element("test") but I only want to hide then next element("target") continue the operation on other "test" elements.

example html:

```
<div class="cart-item-block cart-item-option-list">
  <div class="cart-item-option">
    <span class="cart-item-option-name">
   Select card type:
  </span>

  <span class="cart-item-option-value">
    Standard Card
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-item-option">
      <span class="cart-item-option-name">
       Add a personal message ($2 extra for Standard cards):
  </span>

  <span class="cart-item-option-value">
    No
  </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cart-item-block cart-item-giftwrap">
  <div class="giftwrap-item">
   <a class="giftwrap-item-add" href="#" data-item-giftwrap="d55d1fd6-1ad6-4766-a769-0843e950008e" data-text-short="Add" data-text-long="Add Personal Message">
    <svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#icon-increment-regular"></use></svg>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="cart-item-block cart-item-option-list">
<div class="cart-item-option">
  <span class="cart-item-option-name">
   Select card type:
  </span>

  <span class="cart-item-option-value">
    Standard Card
  </span>
</div>
<div class="cart-item-option">
  <span class="cart-item-option-name">
    Add a personal message ($2 extra for Standard cards):
  </span>

  <span class="cart-item-option-value">
    Yes
  </span>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="cart-item-block cart-item-giftwrap">
 <div class="giftwrap-item">
  <a class="giftwrap-item-add" href="#" data-item-giftwrap="d55d1fd6-1ad6-4766-a769-0843e950008e" data-text-short="Add" data-text-long="Add Personal Message">
    <svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#icon-increment-regular"></use></svg>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

So is cases where class="cart-item-option-value" is Yes we display class="giftwrap-item"
And hide when class="cart-item-option-value" is No ..

Here is my current jQuery - which manages to hide ALL class="giftwrap-item" .. FML

```
//jquery to hide giftwrap option in the cart when The value of Add a personal message is No
$(location).attr('href');
if(window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1) {
    var x = $('.cart-item-option-value').text();
    var theTest = 'No';

    if(x.indexOf(theTest) != -1){
            $('.giftwrap-item-add').hide();
       alert( x );
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was the following ..

```
$(location).attr('href');
if(window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1) {
   $(".cart-item-option-value:contains('No')").parent().parent().next().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//jquery to hide giftwrap option in the cart when The value of Add a personal message is No
$(location).attr('href');
if(window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1) {
  $(".cart-item-option-value:contains('No')").parent().parent().next().hide();
}
```

hopefully that sorts it!